# Value of Function Arg Changes on Entrance to Function

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, malloc

Currently I'm having a problem that when I step into a function in gdb the value of the arg changes. I can not for the life of me figure out what this is. As you can see in the function at large the value of `block` is  `0x800000008`. When I print it thats its value and when I inspect the values of args that is its value. Then when I step into `write_block` for some reason the value of `block` changes. But only for this function. When I step out the value of `block` is once again `0x800000008`, the correct value. When I step into the next function the value of `block` is correct again. What gives?

The code is compiled is with the `-O0` optimization flag.

Here is a c code snipped from the function `mm_malloc` in question

```
 if (block == NULL) {
        // Always request at least chunksize
        extendsize = max(asize, chunksize);
        block = extend_heap(extendsize);
        // extend_heap returns an error
        if (block == NULL) {
            return bp;
        }
        remove_free_block(block); // extend_heap guarentees teh block is
        // on the free list
    }

    // The block should be marked as free
    dbg_assert(!get_alloc(block));

    // Mark block as allocated
    size_t block_size = get_size(block);
    write_block(block, block_size, true);

    // Try to split the block if too large
    split_block(block, asize);
```

Output from GDB

````
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  get_alloc (block=0x800000008) at mm.c:399
0x0000000000404b39 in mm_malloc (size=9904) at mm.c:1175
Value returned is $75 = false
(gdb) n
(gdb) s   
get_size (block=0x800000008) at mm.c:323
(gdb) p block
$76 = (block_t *) 0x800000008
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  get_size (block=0x800000008) at mm.c:323
0x0000000000404b77 in mm_malloc (size=9904) at mm.c:1178
Value returned is $77 = 14016
(gdb) step
(gdb) p block
$78 = (block_t *) 0x800000008
(gdb) step

Breakpoint 1, write_block (block=0x80000c3c8, size=14016, alloc=true) at mm.c:440
(gdb) p block
$79 = (block_t *) 0x80000c3c8
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  write_block (block=0x80000c3c8, size=14016, alloc=true) at mm.c:440
mm_malloc (size=9904) at mm.c:1182
(gdb) p block
$80 = (block_t *) 0x800000008
(gdb) step
split_block (block=0x800000008, asize=9920) at mm.c:846
(gdb) p block
$81 = (block_t *) 0x800000008
(gdb) ```
````

Comment: If you are implementing your own memory allocation (which I suspect you are, since you are able to get the size of a previous allocation) the problem could arise anywhere. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows complete code and will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes I am implementing my own version of `malloc` Could you clarify the comment, "the problem could arise anywhere"? Does working in the heap region of memory somehow affect `gdb`? I'll try to put together a Minimal Reproducible Example but that'll be hard to do.

Comment: Without a *demonstrable* effect the reasons would be speculation. If there is undefined behaviour somewhere I am unsure how that might affect what is reported.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the Minimal Reproducible Example as this is a school assignment. I did solve the underlying issue which got rid of my need to use gdb. I however have no explanation for why gdb was showing the incorrect values.

Answer (score 0):

> When I step into the next function the value of block is correct again. What gives?

The debug info *describing* to GDB how to find the value of `block` is either incorrect / inaccurate, *or* GDB is not interpreting the debug info correctly.

The former is quite common, especially in optimized code, or when using older compilers. Usually executing a few `stepi`s to step past the function prolog makes GDB display correct values again.

Comment: I was using `stepi` and verifying that the value in the function was the value that gdb was showing. Furthermore this code was compiled with `-O0` which I believe doesn't include that many optimizations. Either way I solved the problem. I'm still not sure why gdb wasn't displaying the correct value however.

Comment: @MilesConn  "I'm still not sure why" -- I am 99% sure it's for one of the two reasons I provided.